# How to setup multi languages title

Tags: gitbook

In a classic multi languages Gitbook, is there a way to setup different titles based on the languages of the book?

the langs.md

```
* [English](en/)
* [French](fr/)
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, a book.json in each language directory specifying the title  should do it.

Comment: Good idea I'll test that

Comment: It doesn't work, I think gitbook.com is using the default repo title to set it.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake. It's working but the one I was hoping to change is the "title" on the top left summary sidebar. I'll dig deeper! Do you mind publishing a short answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can setup different **SUMMARY.md** to setup different titles.
Here is how I setup different titles:

The file structure(find -L):

> ./LANGS.md
>   ./ch
>   ./ch/README.md
>   ./ch/chapter1.md
>   ./ch/SUMMARY.md
>   ./en
>   ./en/README.md
>   ./en/chapter1.md
>   ./en/SUMMARY.md

LANGS.md :

> # Languages
>
> * [English](en/)
>   * [Chinese](ch/)

./ch/SUMMARY.md:

> # 前言
>
> * [前言](README.md)
>   * [第一章](chapter1.md)

./en/SUMMARY.md :

> # Summary
>
> * [Introduction](README.md)
>   * [First Chapter](chapter1.md)

Comment: Hello @willow, thanks for the answer. It's been a while since I ask this. I'll make an attempt with your idea and get back to you if it's working as expected.